# Lumen Passport (dusterio/lumen-passport) - make login accessible

Tags: laravel, authentication, lumen, laravel-passport

I am a novice with Lumen and have recently integrated [dusterio/lumen-passport](https://packagist.org/packages/dusterio/lumen-passport) via composer into my project. Following a tutorial I have successfully created authentication for 'client' instances, so I am able to send variables

```
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: {my id}
client_secret: {my secret}
```

to /oauth/token and get a bearer token. That is working great.

What I need to be able to do, and I cannot find sufficient documentation anywhere, is to **create user login functionality**. This is so that I can hook a UI up to the Lumen API and users be able to enter their email address and password to get access. If any one has any information to help me achieve this I would be extremely grateful. Below are edits I have made to set up the passport process...

bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
 'client.credentials' => Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class,
]);

$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(Dusterio\LumenPassport\PassportServiceProvider::class);
```

config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'api'),
    'passwords' => 'users'
],

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users'
        ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \App\User::class
    ]
],
```

routes/web.php

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'client.credentials'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/test', 'TestController@index');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it with my laravel based client (seperate apps) was to save the token to a cookie which gets called each request using middleware to authenticate the request heres my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class AuthController extends Controller {
public function __construct()
{
}

public function showLoginPage()
{
    return view('Login');
}


public function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $client_id = env('CLIENT_ID');
    $client_secret = env('CLIENT_SECRET');
    $username = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $guzzle = new Client;
    $response = $guzzle->post('https://api.domain.com/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'scope' => '*',
        ],
    ]);
    $reply = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    $token = $reply['access_token'];
    return redirect('/')->cookie('token', $token);
}

public function attemptLogout(Request $request)
{
    $accessToken = $request->cookie('token');

    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.domain.com']);

    $headers = [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Accept'        => 'application/json',
    ];

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'logout', [
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);

    $status = $response->getStatusCode();

    if($status === 200)
    {
        return redirect('/login')->withCookie(Cookie::forget('token'))->with('success','Logout Successful');
    } else {
        return response('API Logout Failed', 500);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This script shows a login page, attempts to do a password grant login and saves the access token to a cookie which a middleware (not shown) uses to authenticate future requests and offers a logout function thats revokes and deletes the access token when the user logsout invalidating all sessions.